# Python Logging - AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'handlers'

Tags: python, logging, handler

Observation: When I comment out `from logging import handlers` the below-mentioned error is observed.

```
Error:
    file_handler =  logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(
AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'handlers'
```

Question: If i have imported the `logging` why is required to do `from logging import handlers`?

```
import logging
import sys
#from logging import handlers

def LoggerDefination():
    #file_handler = logging.FileHandler(filename='..\\logs\\BasicLogger_v0.1.log', mode='a')
    file_handler =  logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(
        filename="..\\logs\\BasicLogger_v0.2.log",
        mode='a',
        maxBytes=20000,
        backupCount=7,
        encoding=None,
        delay=0
    )
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    stdout_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    stdout_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    handlers = [file_handler, stdout_handler]

    logging.basicConfig(
        level=logging.DEBUG,
        format='%(asctime)s | %(module)s | %(name)s | LineNo_%(lineno)d | %(levelname)s |  %(message)s',
        handlers=handlers
    )

def fnt_test_log1():
    LoggerDefination()
    WriteLog1 = logging.getLogger('fnt_test_log1')
    #WriteLog1.propagate=False
    WriteLog1.info("######## START OF : test_log1 ##########")
    WriteLog1.debug("test_log1 | This is debug level")
    WriteLog1.debug("test_log1 | This is debug level")
    WriteLog1.info("test_log1 | This is info level")
    WriteLog1.warning("test_log1 | This is warning level")
    WriteLog1.error("test_log1 | This is error level")
    WriteLog1.critical("test_log1 |This is critiacl level")
    WriteLog1.info("######## END OF : test_log1 ##########")


def fnt_test_log2():
    LoggerDefination()
    WriteLog2 = logging.getLogger('fnt_test_log2')
    WriteLog2.info("######## START OF : test_log2 ##########")
    WriteLog2.debug("test_log2 ===> debug")
    WriteLog2.debug("test_log2 | This is debug level")
    WriteLog2.debug("test_log2 | This is debug level")
    WriteLog2.info("test_log2 | This is info level")
    WriteLog2.warning("test_log2 | This is warning level")
    WriteLog2.error("test_log2 | This is error level")
    WriteLog2.critical("test_log2 |This is critiacl level")
    WriteLog2.info("######## STOP OF : test_log2 ##########")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    LoggerDefination()
    MainLog = logging.getLogger('main')
    LoggerDefination()
    MainLog.info("Executing script: " + __file__)
    fnt_test_log1()
    fnt_test_log2()
```

Comment: @amit chopra: I fixed the formatting of your question

Answer (score 20):

This is a two-part answer: The first part concerns your immediate question. The second part concerns the question why your question might have come up in the first place (and, well, how I ended up in this thread, given that your question is already two months old).

**First part (the answer to your question):** When importing a package like `import logging`, Python by default never imports subpackages (or submodules) like `logging.handlers` but only exposes variables to you that are defined in the package's `__init__.py` file (in this case `logging/__init__.py`). Unfortunately, it's hard to tell from the outside if `logging.handlers` is a variable in `logging/__init__.py` or an actual separate module `logging/handlers.py`. So you have to take a look at `logging/__init__.py` and then you will see that it doesn't define a `handlers` variable and that, instead, there's a module `logging/handlers.py` which you need to import separately through `import logging.handlers` or `from logging.handlers import TheHandlerYouWantToUse`. So this should answer your question.

**Second part:** I recently noticed that my IDE (PyCharm) always suggests `import logging` whenever I actually want to use `logging.handlers.QueueHandler`. And for some arcane reason (and despite what I said in the first part) it's been working! …well, most of the time.

Specifically, in the following code, the type annotation causes the expected `AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'handlers'`. However, after commenting out the annotation (which for Python < 3.9 gets executed during module execution time), calling the function works – provided I call it "late enough" (more on that below).

```
import logging
from multiprocessing.queues import Queue


def redirect_logs_to_queue(
    logging_queue: Queue, level: int = logging.DEBUG
) -> logging.handlers.QueueHandler:  # <-------------------------------- This fails

    queue_handler = logging.handlers.QueueHandler(logging_queue)  # <--- This works
    root = logging.getLogger()
    root.addHandler(queue_handler)
    root.setLevel(level)
    return queue_handler
```

So what does "late enough" mean? Unfortunately, my application was a bit too complex to do some quick bug hunting. Nevertheless, it was clear to me that `logging.handlers` must "become available" at some point between start-up (i.e. all my modules getting loaded/executed) and invoking that function. This gave me the decisive hint: Turns out, some another module deep down the package hierarchy was doing `from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler, QueueListener`. This statement loaded the entire `logging.handlers` module and caused Python to "mount" the `handlers` module in its parent package `logging`, meaning that the `logging` variable would henceforth always come equipped with a `handlers` attribute even after a mere `import logging`, which is why I didn't need to `import logging.handlers` anymore (and which is probably what PyCharm noticed).

Try it out yourself:

This works:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import QueueHandler
print(logging.handlers)
```

This doesn't:

```
import logging
print(logging.handlers)
```

All in all, this phenomenon is a result of Python's import mechanism using global state to avoid reloading modules. (Here, the "global state" I'm referring to is the `logging` variable that you get when you `import logging`.) While it is treacherous sometimes (as in the case above), it does make perfect sense: If you `import logging.handlers` in multiple modules, you don't want the code in the `logging.handlers` module to get loaded (and thus executed!) more than once. And so Python just adds the `handlers` attribute to the `logging` module object as soon as you import `logging.handlers` somewhere and since all modules that `import logging` share the same `logging` object, `logging.handlers` will suddenly be available everywhere.

Comment: It is worth noting that the OP's example (`from logging import handlers`) relies on exactly the same side effect described in the latter part of this answer.  Module `logging.handlers` has been imported *as `handlers`*, making it and its contents accessible via that simple name (e.g. `handlers.RotatingFileHandler`).  That actually creates a bit of namespace pollution.  Cleaner if the OP wants to use the fully qualified name anyway would be `import logging.handlers`.

Comment: Also the funny thing is that StreamHandler is in logging/__init__.py and not in logging/handlers.py Sometimes its better to not know how things are tangled under the hood, until something doesn't work as it should.

Answer (score 13):

Perhaps you have some *other* module called `logging` which masks the standard library one. Is there some file called `logging.py` somewhere in your code base?

Answer (score 3):

I came here when searching for similar error `AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'config'`. And I was able to fix it by `import logging.config`.

I suggest that you can fix your with `import logging.handlers`
The reason we need to do it is they was not explicit declares `handlers` in `logging.__init__.py` so we must import it directly - that surprised me too

Answer (score 0):

#### How to diagnose

The best way to figure out the issue is to simply run `python3`, and then the following commands:

```
Python 3.8.10
>>> import logging
>>> logging
<module 'logging' from '/home/user/my_personal_package/logging/__init__.py'>
```

This shows that you are using this OTHER package (`my_personal_package`) instead of the built-in logging package.

It should say:

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging
<module 'logging' from '/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py'>
```

You can also just put this in a program to debug it:

```
import logging
print(logging)
```

---

#### How to fix

Fix this by removing the offending `logging.py` or `logging/__init__.py`.

Answer (score 0):

Add import logging.handlers to use these methods